# create an array from a foreach loop of select tag and pass it through php form

Tags: php, arrays, forms, select

i dont know how to express it better, but i think my coding show reveal my problem.. am trying to get a select tag list of values from a foreach loop and convert them to an array then pass it using a form post action, i got stuck retrieving the select tag value array from the loop.. heres my code

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo base_url();?>index.php?admin/manage_attendance/


<?php 
//STUDENTS ATTENDANCE

 foreach($students as $row)
        {
 ?>

<select name="status" class="form-control" style="width:100px; float:left;">
<option value="0" <?php if($status == 0)echo 'selected="selected"';?>></option>
<option value="1" <?php if($status == 1)echo 'selected="selected"';?>>Present</option>
<option value="2" <?php if($status == 2)echo 'selected="selected"';?>>Absent</option>
</select>


<?php 
} 
?>

<input type="submit" class="btn btn-default"    value="save" style="float:left; margin:0px 10px;">
</form>
```

Comment: i'm guessing the fact that your `action` attribute and your `form` tag is not closed (missing `">` at the end of the first line) is just a typo, right?

Comment: what's the content of `$students` and how does `$status` get generated in your code?

Comment: sorry that was a typo.. the $status is a data output from the database... the form is literally for updating attendance information in a school management software.. i hv found a soultion my self already thanks :)

Comment: don't hesitate to share that as an answer, it is allowed, if it's precisely providing the actual answer with details on what you did and how you solved it.

Answer (score 0):

your code of

```
<select name="status" class="form-control" style="width:100px; float:left;">...
</select>
```

is inside of foreach loop, of course it will executed for each loop. Maybe you can put it outside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

i jus got a simple solution.. i just wrote few parts of the codes ealier, my solution was to add an array as the name attribute of the select tag, making the foreach statement fill the array up while looping it, here is the full code

index.php?admin/manage_attendance/">

```
    <?php 
        //STUDENTS ATTENDANCE

        foreach($students as $row)
        {
            ?>
            <tr class="gradeA">
                <td><?php echo $row['roll'];?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['name'];?></td>
                <td align="center">

                    <?php 
                    //inserting blank data for students attendance if unavailable
                    $verify_data    =   array(  'student_id' => $row['student_id'],
                                                'date' => $full_date);
                    $query = $this->db->get_where('attendance' , $verify_data);
                    if($query->num_rows() < 1)
                    $this->db->insert('attendance' , $verify_data);

                    //showing the attendance status editing option
                    $attendance = $this->db->get_where('attendance' , $verify_data)->row();
                    $status     = $attendance->status;
                    ?>


                        <select name="status[]" class="form-control" style="width:100px; float:left;">
                            <option value="0" <?php if($status == 0)echo 'selected="selected"';?>></option>
                            <option value="1" <?php if($status == 1)echo 'selected="selected"';?>>Present</option>
                            <option value="2" <?php if($status == 2)echo 'selected="selected"';?>>Absent</option>
                        </select>
                        <input type="hidden" name="student_id"          value="<?php echo $row['student_id'];?>" />
                        <input type="hidden" name="date"                    value="<?php echo $full_date;?>" />

            <?php 
        }

        ?>
        <input type="text" name="test"                  value="<?php echo $string?>" />
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default"    value="save" style="float:left; margin:0px 10px;">
                    </form>
```